# What is the equivalent for sql loader in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

What is the equivalent for sqlldr(used for oracle) in postgresql?

I am trying to find equivalent for sql loader utility(sqlldr) in postgres.

Comment: A built-in equivalent it would be `copy`. An external equivalent would be pgloader

Answer (score 1):

pg loader emulates oracles sql loader:

http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgloader/

pg bulkload is used to load lots of data in an otherwise offline db. Useful for large data warehouses, fast, and somewhat dangerous and quirky:

http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/